# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{i\,t\,x}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{dz}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

So all in all there can be defined instead $\displaystyle{ \int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm{dz} = \int_{C} \dfrac{e^{i\,t\,z}}{z^2+1}\,\mathrm{dz}}=\displaystyle{\int_{\gamma_1}\dfrac{e^{i\,t\,z}}{z^2+1}\,\mathrm{dz}} + \displaystyle{\int_{\gamma_2} \dfrac{e^{i\,t\,x}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{dx}}$

where $\gamma_1 = R\,e^{i\,\varphi} \quad\varphi\in[0, \pi] $ and $\gamma_2 = a,\quad a\in[-R, R]$

After some estimations done before $\displaystyle{\lim_{R\to\infty}}\displaystyle{\int_{\gamma_1}\dfrac{e^{i\,t\,z}}{z^2+1}\,\mathrm{dz}} = 0$

Hence evaluating $\displaystyle{ \int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm{dz}} $ is like solving the original integral. My questions concern this process:

That integral should be fairly easy to evaluate using Residue theorem: $\displaystyle{ \int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm{dz}}  = 2\,\pi\,i\,\text{Res$(i)$} = \lim_{z \to i}f(z)\,(z-i) = \pi\,e^{-t}$

However according to the solutions on Wiki one also has to consider the integral over $\gamma_1 = R\,e^{i\,\varphi} \quad \varphi \in[0,-\pi]$

Not only that I don't understand why, I also find a different value: $\displaystyle{ \int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm{dz}}  = 2\,\pi\,i\,\text{Res$(-i)$} = \lim_{z \to -i}f(z)\,(z+i) = -\pi\,e^{t}$. According to Wiki that second Integral should equal $\pi\,e^{t}$, what I can't comprehend. Also it is being said that the total value of the sought integral: $\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{i\,t\,x}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{dz}}$ should equal $\pi\,e^{-|t|}$ where I'm asking myself again: Why that absolute value after all?

Comment: You have to also consider the integral over the lower semicircular contour in the case that $t<0$ because if you consider the original contour (the upper semicircle) then the integral over the arc does not vanish as $R\to \infty$.

Comment: The contours should be oriented properly if you want to use the residue theorem.

Comment: The wiki [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_2_%E2%80%93_Cauchy_distribution) quotes Jordan's lemma.  If you follow the link to Jordan's lemma, you'll see why you have to split it into cases.

Comment: The answer is correct; here is an alternative for the problem of $t<0$: reduce to the case of $t\ge 0$ before setting it up as a contour integral. 

If $t = -|t|\le 0$, we have by changing variables $x = -y$ (so $dx = -dy$ and the integral runs the other way)
$$ \int_{-a}^b \frac{e^{-i|t|x}}{x^2+1} dx = -\int_{a}^{-b} \frac{e^{+i|t|y}}{y^2+1} dy= \int_{-b}^a \frac{e^{i|t|y}}{y^2+1}dy$$

So if the integral is say $I(t)$, this shows that $I(t) = I(-t)$.

Comment: Nice. that reasoning seems easier than what I wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I don't have all the details but I think the intuition goes something like this. The problem is that you separated the integral over $C$ as two separate paths. Computing the integral over $C$ is only useful (using residues) if the first integral (over $\gamma_1$) vanishes. The problem is when does it vanish. You claimed that
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{e^{itz}}{z^2+1}dz = 0
$$
but I don't think that is the case for all $t$. Intuitively, that integral will vanish if $e^{itz}$ does not dominate the term $1/(z^2+1)$. Note that for the curve $\gamma_1$ we have $z = R\cos(\varphi)+iR\sin(\varphi), \varphi\in[0,\pi]$ and $\sin(\varphi)\geq 0$ in that interval. Thus,
$$
e^{itz}=e^{iRt\cos(\varphi)}e^{-Rt\sin(\varphi)}
$$
Hence, if $t<0$, the term $e^{-Rt\sin(\varphi)}$ will prevent $\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{e^{itz}}{z^2+1}dz$ to vanish as $R\to\infty$ since the exponent is positive.

Therefore, the original curve only works for $t\geq 0$, which force us to choose a different curve $C'$ for $t<0$, namely the opposite semicircle with $\varphi\in[-\pi,0]$ (which works since $\sin(\varphi)<0$ for $\varphi\in[-\pi,0]$).

Now, in the case of $C$ (the one with $\varphi\in[0,\pi]$), note that this semicircle encloses the upper half of the complex plane. Hence, the curve $C$ encloses the pole $z=i$, so that the value of the integral is $\pi e^{-t}, t\geq 0$ as you obtained, which is obviously equal to $\pi e^{-|t|}$ since $t\geq 0$. In the case of $C'$, the curve encloses the pole $z=-i$, which results in $\pi e^{t}, t<0$. In your question, you obtained $-\pi e^{t}$ but note that $C'$ will traverse the real line in the opposite direction than $C$, thus the sign change. Moreover, note that since $t<0$, we have $t = -|t|$. Thus the value of the original integral using the second curve $C'$ will result in $\pi e^{-|t|}, t<0$.

Therefore, in any case for $t<0$ or $t\geq 0$ the result is the same: $\pi e^{-|t|}$.

Comment: thank you for explaining all that in detail. I got behind it now. Only thing uncovered is why my Residue for $z = -i$ is wrong:$\displaystyle{ \int_Cf(z)\,\mathrm{dz}}  = 2\,\pi\,i\,\text{Res$(-i)$} = 2\,\pi\,i\,\lim_{z \to -i}\dfrac{e^{i\,t\,z}}{(z-i)\,(z+i)}\,(z+i) = -\pi\,e^{t}$

Comment: You mean the minus sign multiplying $\pi$? The contour integral and residue is correct. But the thing is that the curves must be correctly oriented to use the residue theorem. That curve (lower semi circle) will traverse the real line in the opposite direction from what you need (counter clock wise) obtaining an integral $\int_\infty^{-\infty}$ instead of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ as you needed. Hence you use an additional minus sign to flip the limits. Let me know if it is clear now

Comment: Alright now I can reproduce the solution. Again, thank you for all those details, I really needed that.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!